# Distribution of $\arctan(X/Y)$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, polar-coordinates

Given $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables with a standard normal distribution, I've been asked to calculate thee distribution of $Z=\arctan(X/Y)$. For that I thought about calculating the cumulative distribution function of $Z$  and then take its derivative.
So $P(Z \leq  t)$ would be:

$$ \iint_{R}^{ } \frac{1}{2\pi } e^{\frac{-(x^{2}+y^{2})}{2}} $$

where $R=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R : \arctan(x/y) \leq  t)\}$

Then I thought about solving the integral by using polar coordinates, but I'm not sure what the boundaries for $r$ and $\theta$ should be.

Comment: By rotational symmetry, the polar argument is uniform in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: See https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.4218/etrij.10.0210.0201 for a more general case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a very standard approach, as follows.

First perform a change of variables
$$
\begin{cases}
U = \arctan\left(\frac{X}{Y}\right)\\
V = X.
\end{cases}
$$
If you invert the relationships, they become
$$
\begin{cases}
X = V\\
Y = V\cot U.
\end{cases}
$$

The Jacobian of this transformation is
$$J = \left|
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
-\frac{V}{\sin^2 U} & \cot U
\end{array} 
\right| = \frac{V}{\sin^2 U}.$$

The joint distribution of $(U,V)$ is

$$f_{U,V}(u,v) = f_{X,Y}(v,v\cot u) |J|,$$
*limited to the correct domain*, which we can find by considering the codomain of the functions involved in the original change of variables. In our case, the domain is
$$ D_{U,V}=\left(-\frac{\pi}2; \frac{\pi}2\right) \times  \Bbb R.$$

So we have

$$ f_{U,V}(u,v) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-\frac{v^2+v^2\cot^2 u}2} \cdot \left|\frac{v}{\sin^2 u}\right| &((u,v) \in D_{U,V})\\
0 & ((u,v) \not\in D_{U,V}),
\end{cases}
$$
that is, with some simplifications,
$$ f_{U,V}(u,v) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-\frac{v^2}{2\sin^2 u}} \cdot \frac{|v|}{\sin^2 u} &((u,v) \in D_{U,V})\\
0 & ((u,v) \not\in D_{U,V}).
\end{cases}
$$
Finally, by integration we obtain the marginal distribution you need.

$$f_U(u)= \begin{cases} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{U,V}(u,v) dv & -\frac{\pi}2 \leq u \leq \frac{\pi}2 \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise}.\end{cases}\tag{1}\label{1}$$

With the change of variables $t = v^2/2\sin^2 u$ the integral becomes
\begin{eqnarray} 
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{U,V}(u,v) dv &=& \frac1{2\pi}\left[\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-t}dt-\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-t}dt\right]=\\
&=&\frac1{\pi} \int_0^{+\infty}e^{-t}dt = \frac1{\pi}.
\end{eqnarray}

Using \eqref{1} leads to the conclusion that $U$ has uniform distribution between $-\frac{\pi}2$ and $\frac{\pi}2$.

---

If, instead, you want to use the approach you mention (in this case it's faster), then consider the inequality

$$U = \arctan\left(\frac{X}{Y}\right) < \alpha.$$

If $0\leq \alpha \leq \frac{\pi}2$, the condition is satisfied by the points $(X,Y)$ in the red shaded region (Figure below).

[image]

So in this case, using the symmetry of the original distribution, we get, for the CDF of $U$,
\begin{eqnarray}
F_U(\alpha) &=& P(U < \alpha) = \frac1{\pi}\int_0^{+\infty}\int_{\pi/2-\alpha}^{\pi} e^{-\frac{\rho^2}2}\rho d\theta d\rho=\\
&=& \left(\frac12+\frac{\alpha}{\pi}\right)\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{\rho^2}2}\rho d\rho=\\
&=&\left(\frac12+\frac{\alpha}{\pi}\right).
\end{eqnarray}

If $-\frac{\pi}2 \leq \alpha \leq 0$, the points $(X,Y)$ that satisfy the relationship are in the blue shaded region below.

[image]

This gives again

\begin{eqnarray}
F_U(\alpha) &=& P(U < \alpha) = \frac1{\pi}\int_0^{+\infty}\int_{\pi/2-\alpha}^{\pi} e^{-\frac{\rho^2}2}\rho d\theta d\rho=\\
&=&\left(\frac12+\frac{\alpha}{\pi}\right).
\end{eqnarray}

In conclusion,
$$
F_U(\alpha) =
\begin{cases}
\left(\frac12+\frac{\alpha}{\pi}\right) & \left(|\alpha| \leq \frac{\pi}2\right)\\
0 & \mbox{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$
which clearly is a CDF of a uniform distribution between $-\frac{\pi}2$ and $\frac{\pi}2$.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we'll find distribution of $W= \frac{X}{Y}$. Consider vector $V = (X,Y)$ with density $f_V(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}$.

$F_W(t)= \mathbb P(W \le t) = \mathbb P( \frac{X}{Y} \le t) = \mathbb P( (X \le tY, Y\ge 0) \cup (X \ge tY, Y < 0)) = \mathbb P(X \le tY, Y\ge 0) + \mathbb P( (X \ge tY, Y < 0)= \mathbb P( V \in A_t) + \mathbb P( V \in B_t) = \mu_V(A_t) + \mu_V(B_t)$, where:

$\mu_v(C) = \int_C f_V(v) d\lambda_2(v)$, $A_t = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : y\ge 0, x \le yt\}, B_t = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : y< 0, x \ge yt\}$.

That is:

$\mu_V(A_t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{yt} e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}} dxdy$

$ \mu_V(B_t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{0} \int_{yt}^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}} dxdy $

Note, that functions $t \to \mu_V(A_t), t \to \mu_V(B_t)$ are continuosly differentiable, so $F_w$ as a function of $t$ is, too.

We get: $f_W(t) = \frac{dF_W}{dt}(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{d}{dt}(\int_0^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{yt} e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}} dxdy + \int_{-\infty}^{0} \int_{yt}^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}} dxdy) $

$ =\frac{1}{2\pi}(\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{d}{dt} \int_{-\infty}^{yt} e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}dxdy + \int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{d}{dt}\int_{yt}^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}} dxdy) = $

$= \frac{1}{2\pi}(\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}( \frac{d}{dt}(G(yt) - G(-\infty)) )dy + \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}( \frac{d}{dt}( G(+\infty) - G(yt)))dy)$, where $G(x) = \int e^\frac{-x^2}{2}dx$. So $\frac{d}{dt}G(yt) = ye^\frac{-(yt)^2}{2}$.

So that we get:

$f_W(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}(\int_0^{+\infty} ye^{-\frac{y^2(t^2+1)}{2}}dy - \int_{-\infty}^0 ye^{-\frac{y^2(t^2+1)}{2}}dy)$. The same substitution $ w = \frac{y^2}{2} $, gives us:

$f_W(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}(\int_0^\infty e^{-w(t^2+1)} dw + \int_0^\infty e^{-w(t^2+1)} dw  ) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\infty e^{-w(t^2+1)}dw = \frac{1}{(t^2+1)\pi}$. Luckily it integrates to one ;).

So now, as we have $W$, we can look at the distribution of $Z=\arctan(W)$

$F_Z(t) = \mathbb P( Z \le t ) = \mathbb P( \arctan(W) \le t) $. So at this point, for $t\le -\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have $F_Z(t) = 0$, and for $t \ge \frac{\pi}{2}$, we have $F_Z(t) = 1$. Let's take any $t \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$.

$F_Z(t) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\tan(t)} \frac{1}{(t^2+1)} = \frac{1}{\pi}(\arctan(\tan(t)) - \arctan(-\infty)) = \frac{t}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2}.$

So, taking derivative of $F_Z$ (as we see, it is piecewise continuously differentiable), we have, that the density of $Z$ is $f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{\pi} \chi_{(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})}$, so to conclude $Z \sim \mathcal U((-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}))$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Try to use $\pi/2 - \arctan(y/x)=\arctan(x/y)$.

If $(x,y) = (r \cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$  where $r>0$ and $\pi/2>\theta>0$ then for any real number $t$, the following are equivalent:

1. $\arctan(x/y) \leq t$
2. $\pi/2 - \arctan(y/x) \leq t$
3. $\pi/2 - \theta \leq t$
4. $\pi/2 - t \leq \theta$

This should help you to get the right limits for the integration.

Also, notice that changing $r$ does not affect whether  $\pi/2 - t \leq \theta$.

Comment: I get the equivalences, but why should I assume those first conditions over r and the angle?

Comment: You should not assume that $\pi/2>\theta>0$.  I just figured that if you could find the cumulative distribution function for random points in the first quadrant, then it would not be too hard to extend the answer to the other quadrants.