# Closed-form for $\int_0^{a^2} \mathrm{Ei} (-s) \frac{1 - e^s}{s} ds$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, special-functions, polylogarithm

In my partial answer to this question: [Integral involving polylogarithm and an exponential](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4372464/integral-involving-polylogarithm-and-an-exponential/4372842#4372842), I arrive at the integral

$$ \int_0^{a^2} \mathrm{Ei} (-s) \frac{1 - e^s}{s} ds , ~~~~ (\ast) $$

where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathrm{Ei}$ is the standard exponential integral defined by
$$ \mathrm{Ei} (z) = \int_{-\infty}^z \frac{e^t}{t} d t , $$
where the Cauchy principal value is taken for $z > 0$. The integral ($\ast$) is very similar to the integrals #28, #30, and #31 on page 198 of https://ia600303.us.archive.org/1/items/jresv73Bn3p191/jresv73Bn3p191_A1b.pdf. I haven't been able to complete the connection. Does anyone know how to express ($\ast$) in terms of known special functions?

Comment: Mathematica gives the particularly nasty result
$$
\frac{1}{2} \left(-2 a^2 \, _3F_3(1,1,1;2,2,2;-a^2)+4 a^2 \,
   _3F_3(1,1,1;2,2,2;a^2)+{_1F_1}^{(2,0,0)}(0,1,a^2)-{_1F_1}^{
   (2,0,0)}(0,1,0)+2 (\log a^2+\gamma) (-\text{Ei}(a^2)+\log a^2+\gamma )\right),
$$
where ${_1F_1}^{(2,0,0)}(a,b,x)=\partial_\alpha^2\,{_1F_1}(\alpha,\beta,z)|_{\alpha=a,\beta=b,z=x}$.  I would have to spend some time considering how this result is derived.

Comment: Thank you. I probably should have noted that I ran Mathematica as well and found the same. From experience, I have found that Mathematica may return a complicated result when, in fact, a simpler expression is possible. I am hoping this is also the case here and the hypergeometric functions may be simplified.

Comment: It does appear that this simplifies. For example, ${_1F_1}^{(2,0,0)}(0,1,0)=0$ and ${_1F_1}^{(2,0,0)}(0,1,a^2)=\log^2(1-a^2)$. The other hypergeometric functions look like they will also simplify to more elementary functions.

Comment: You also have formulas like [this](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.31.03.0134.01) that define your ${_3F_3}$ functions as a limit with $c\to 1$.

Comment: Thank you. I will see what I can make of this. I do wonder why Mathematica returns terms that are automatically zero…

Comment: @AaronHendrickson ${_1 F_1}^{(2, 0, 0)}(0; 1; a^2) = \ln^2(1 - a^2)$ cannot be correct, the derivative doesn't have a singularity at $a = 1$. In terms of the G-function, the integral is
$$G_{3, 4}^{2, 3} {\left( a^2 \middle| {1, 1, 1 \atop 1, 1, 0, 0} \right)} -
 a^2 \hspace {1 px} {_3 F_3}(1, 1, 1; 2, 2, 2; -a^2)$$
(the residues at the multiple poles give the polygamma terms corresponding to the derivative of $(\alpha)_k$).

Comment: The derivative of a hypergeometric function with respect to a parameter is a double sum hypergeometric function, but this double sum may not simplify.