# $\arctan(X/Y)$ distribution when $X$ and $Y$ dependent

Tags: probability, trigonometry

I would like to know that if this solution holds when $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. I couldn't see anything related with the independency.

[Distribution of $\arctan(X/Y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3308943/distribution-of-arctanx-y)

If not so, I'd appreciate some guidance to find out the PDF for $Z=\arctan(X/Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are uniform and $X \not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp Y$

Regards.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "I would like to know that if this solution holds when $X$ and $Y$ are not independent." 
Obviously not. Consider $X=Y$

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, then they will have some covariance(they are normal distributed). So having the covariance , will specify the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ on $\Bbb{R}^{2}$ (i.e. you will know the density) . Now use the same method to find the joint distribution of $(U,V)$ with the required changes in the density. Now you havve to integrate over $V$ to get the marginal density of $U$ . That part might be the tricky one as it might not have a closed form(or it might , I have not checked). In any case, you will find an expression.